# Cutting out a part of a field of lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

I made a field of lines evenly spaced in illustrator.  They are grouped together.  I want to cut out and paste a segment of this group.  The grouped lines are parallel and the group is tilted at an angle; I wanted to cut out a vertical segment so I have a strip of trapezoidal shapes to paste elsewhere.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The long-winded method one which will allow you to only copy trapezoidal shapes.

### To reduce art to standard shapes only

- Copy lines to new layer
- Hide visibility of old layer
- Select lines, `Object > Expand`
- Draw rectangle of area you want to retain.
- Select lines and rectangle
- click **Crop** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**
- Draw a no-fill, no stroke, rectangle
- Choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke`
- Hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key.
- Select the lines (which are now trapezoidal shapes)
- Copy
- Paste wherever you want.
- **Possible Problem** with this method is the lines are not easily edited now. So should you need to alter the angle, you'll have to repeat the steps above. Any non-proportional scaling will change *all* angles of the lines, including the ends. In addition, reuse of this artwork will increase overall file size.

A second method....

### Mask the lines rather than editing them.

- Draw a rectangle on top of the lines for the area you want to retain.
- Select the lines and rectangle
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`
- **Possible problems** with this method is the need to edit clipping mask contents should you need to edit the internal lines. Not a huge hurdle, but depending upon the artwork, it can be time-consuming.  In addition, reuse of this artwork will increase overall file size.

A third (preferred here) method....

### Simply use a pattern and rotate the pattern.

- Create a *straight* horizontal or vertical line **pattern** by simply dragging a series of strokes or shapes to the **Swatches Panel** - Be certain to double-check the odd/even rules so the pattern repeats correctly.
- Fill **any** shape with the pattern
- Choose `Object > Transform > Rotate` and **uncheck** the "Transform Objects' option - which will check the "Transform Patterns" option - and then enter the amount of pattern rotation you desire. This results in angled pattern lines within the shape.
- **Benefits** to this method are pattern angles can be changed at any future point for reuse and ease of editing and non-proportional scaling of the pattern object will *not* result in angles being altered (or if the angles are altered, then can be reset with a click). And file size is not increased when the same pattern is applied to multiple objects (even if the pattern angles are different).